# Finding the Units Digit to 7 to the 2945

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would I go about finding the Units Digit to 7^(2945)?

I know that:
7^0 = 1

7^1 = 7

7^2 = 49

7^3 = 343

7^4 = 2401

...

7^9 = 40353607

Comment: What pattern do you see in the units digits of that sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you know $7^4$ is a number whose units digit is 1. You can write $7^{2945}$ as $7^{(736\times 4+1)}$ or alternately as $(7^4)^{736}7^1$ as the first factor when simplified  will be a number whose units digit is 1 so the answer is a number ending with "7" as its unit digit...

Comment: Guide to the MathJax formula (and much else) formatting tool: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

when u are interested only in the unit digit you can multiply step by step like u did in your post but you can forget the other digits.

So you have $$7^2 = 49$$ however you forget what was it exactly and u only remember that $$7^2 = x\cdot 10 + 9 $$
you multiply again
$$7^3=7^2 \cdot 7 = 70x+63 = (7x+6) \cdot 10+3$$
yet again you only remembering that it looked like
$$7^3=x_3 \cdot 10 +3$$ 
as you can see you dont have to remember $7^9 = 40353607$, $7^9 =x_9 \cdot 10 +7$ will be enougth

so now we can repeat you what u did but make it simpler. We can note that

- if the $7^n$ ends with $1$ then $7^{n+1}$ ends with 7
- if the $7^n$ ends with $7$ then $7^{n+1}$ ends with 9
- if the $7^n$ ends with $1$ then $7^{n+1}$ ends with 3
- if the $7^n$ ends with $1$ then $7^{n+1}$ ends with 1

so the sequence of units digits will be $(1,7,9,3,1,7,3,9,\ldots)$

now you want 2945th element of that sequence. The value repeats itself evey 4 steps.$$a_n=a_{n-4}$$
and also
$$a_n=a_{n-20}$$
$$a_n=a_{n-100}$$

so u can say that:
$$a_{2945}=a_{45}=a_5=a_1=7^1=7$$

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to verify that$$7^{4n+k}\equiv 7,9,3,1\pmod{10}\text{  when }k=1,2,3,4 \text{ respectively}$$ Hence
$$7^{2945}=7^{4\cdot736+1}=(7^{736})^4\cdot 7\equiv 7\pmod{10}$$